# Building APK with AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

Using AOSP we can build own Android with some features.

I have setup environment using google documentation and another web sites, and in tutorials says -

> make adb fastboot. Update yours android OS with yours customization.

But i just need use `@SystemApi` classes for build one app, what i should to do?

I searched in web for one month, but still didn't find.

Comment: Are you able to build & flash the .img ? If so, just remove @SystemApi, and use the android.jar from the build instead of the ones from android-sdk

Comment: @RickSanchez, what did you mean by build and flash .img? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Methods marked as **@hide** or **@SystemAPI** are not part of the official SDK, and are not intended to be used generally.

Yet, until lately you could access all of them either by ***Reflection***, or by using a ***custom android.jar*** that has those methods too. See this project for the list of android.jar: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

***If your Android version is below P, that's all you need to do. Otherwise keep reading:***

In Android P, [Google removed access to non-SDK interfaces](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html), so you cannot use those methods as above. In this case you'd have to remove the @SystemApi and @hide annotations from the classes and methods you need, compile and flash the update to the device. Then you can use the above methods